# Can anyone see where the infinite loop in my program is?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

The purpose of this program is to find the smallest number evenly divisible by all integers 1 through 20.  I know it could be made more efficient, but I'm not interested in optimizing it right now.  When I execute the program, it seems to hang forever, which leads me to believe that there's an infinite loop somewhere.  I can't seem to find it though.  I'm not sure what part of the code is causing the problem and it's relatively concise, so I'll post it all here.

```
public class Problem5{
  public static void main(String[]args){

    boolean notFound = true;
    while(notFound){
      int n = 20;
      if(testDivide(n)){
        System.out.println(n);
        notFound = false;
      }
      else
        n++;
    }
  }

  private static boolean testDivide(int target){
    for(int i = 20; i > 0; i--){
      if(target % i != 0)
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

If anyone can help me out with this, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Additional Information: The program also never outputs any numbers, which leads me to believe that `if(testDivide(n))` is never evaluating to true.

Comment: Are you sure `notFound` will be set to false in all cases?

Comment: Here's a hint: it's the while loop.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging at all?

Comment: I thought it should be set to false anytime `testDivide` returned `true`, and `testDivide` should return `true` when the program finds a number that's divisible by all integers from 1 to 20.  Clearly I've made a mistake somewhere though, since the program doesn't work.

Comment: You are initializing the value of `n` inside your while loop to `20`, since `n` is always 20 for testDivide(20), which will always return false since `20 % 19 != 0` returns `false`. Hence remove `int n = 20` from your while loop.

Comment: Oh, that's so obvious!  I can't believe I didn't see that!  I asked a friend too, and he also missed it.  You guys are really great, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing the value of `n` inside your while loop to `20`, since `n` is always 20 for testDivide(20), which will always return false since `20 % 19 != 0` returns `false`. Hence remove `int n = 20` from your while loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I spent so long fiddling with the conditions on my loops and control statements, I completely missed that.  It's such a simple fix.  Thank you!

Comment: But `20 % 20 = 0` since the remainder is always zero, which would lead the for loop to decrement the counter by one, test it's termination condition, and again `20` will be evaluated in the expression with decremented value of `i`, when in this case it will return false, IMHO. Might be I am missing somethong, just woke up, and answering this question with my eyes half open :-).

Comment: @realityChemist : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: Going back through my old questions I realized I never actually accepted your answer!  So there you go, that should be some rep for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean notFound = true;
while(notFound){
    int n = 20;
```

should be

```
boolean notFound = true;
int n = 20;
while(notFound) {
```

Answer (score 1):

your for loop makes sure you return false, and then your while loop always sets i to 20 this is your infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

See the `while` loop:

```
while(notFound){
      int n = 20;
      if(testDivide(n)){
        System.out.println(n);
        notFound = false;
      }
      else
        n++;
    }
```

When the `while` loop is executed first, the value of `n` is set to `20`.

the test divide returns false.
The value of `n` is decremented to `19`.
The loop executes again
The value of of `n` is reinitialized to `20`.
This is the problem initialize `n` outside the `while` loop.